# Como fazer um botão "voltar ao topo" em uma página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como eu posso fazer um botão voltar ao topo em uma página html?

Jquery, javascript, o que seria melhor?

Answer (score 12):

Usando Jquery

```
//scroll normal
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);

//scroll suave
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); //slow, medium, fast
```

Usando Javascript

```
var scrollTop = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Comment: E como eu coloco efeito? Para suavizar a ida para o topo.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 8):

A melhor forma vai depender das suas necessidades.

Além da forma apresentada pelo Mauro, pode utilizar somente html apontado o `href` do link para o trecho da página que fique no topo:

```html
<span id='topo'></span>

<p>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br> 
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
</p>

<a href='#topo'>Voltar ao topo</a>
```

Comment: +1 Solução limpa e objetiva, e funciona mesmo com JS desligado. Não faz parte da pergunta, mas se ele quiser scroll animado, tem scripts pra isso sem perder a compatibilidade. Eis um sem jQuery: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/blob/master/src/js/smooth-scroll.js e um com https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-197181