# Atalho botão home para subir o site?

Tags: html, html5, wordpress

Tenho um site, e o cliente pediu que quando clicasse no botão home DO TECLADO site subisse por inteiro. Como eu faço?

Comment: Duplicada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161986/4808

Answer (score 0):

Usando Jquery

```
//scroll normal
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);

//scroll suave
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); //slow, medium, fast
```

Usando Javascript

```
var scrollTop = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

> Sugestão de [Francis Vagner da Luz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73990/francis-vagner-da-luz)

`HTML` apontado o `href` do link para o trecho da página que fica no topo:

```
<span id='topo'></span>

<p>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br> 
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
  bla bla <br> bla bla <br> bla bla <br>
</p>

<a href='#topo'>Voltar ao topo</a>
```

Comment: Você também pode colocar uma DIV  no topo do site com um id.. Aí depois é só colocar no botão home, no href o nome deste id ao invés de uma URL.. Se quiser postar seu código eu posso te mostrar melhor.